# Como fazer 'Loop' em 'Array' multidimensional em Bash?

Tags: array, loop, script, bash, array-multidimensional

*Situação:*

Preciso criar um script com array multidimensional. Exemplo:

**Tabela 1** >> Campos **id** e **nome**

**Tabela 2** >> Campos **id** e **telefone**

*Script atual:*

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
arr[tabela1]=id
arr[tabela2]=id

for i in "${!arr[@]}"
do
        echo "Tabela: $i"
        echo "Campo: ${arr[$i]}"
done

return
```

*Problema:*

Como fazer um array multidimensional e um *loop* para inserir, além do 'id' conforme script acima, várias colunas; exemplo: 'nome', 'telefone' etc, conforme demonstrado na *Situação*?

Obrigado!

Comment: Bash não suporta (directamente) arrays multidemencionais. Podes dar a volta ao problema (1) usando (strings, textos, etc) com separadores a vários níveis (EX: CVS), (mesmo dentro da valores de Arrays bash), (2) usando XML, JSON ou (3) migrando para perl, python, ruby, etc.

Comment: Obrigado @JJoao!

Comment: Se precisares de ajuda com exemplificação de alguma das "propostas", diz!

Comment: @JJoao obrigado!! Estava precisando para montar um script e atender essa demanda referente ao link abaixo, mas no final deu tudo certo. muitíssimo Obrigado!! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86491/manter-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ao-alterar-url-wordpress-tema-adventure-organic-them/86665#86665

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer um array que armazena informações **id** e **nome**. Caso seja...

Criar array em bash é mais simples do que imagina. Exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_( "nome1" "nome2" "nome3" )
#technique 1 for print all elements
echo "${array_[@]:0}"
#technique 2 for print all elements
for ((id=0; id<{#$array_[@]}; id++)); do
  echo "Bands: ${array_[$id]}"
done
```

ps: Em bash, o uso de `${#array[@]}` é o mesmo que dizer: – "Ei `array`, quantos elementos estão armazenados em você?"

Usando o exemplo acima para imprimir o **nome**, pode ser feito algo assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
bands=("slayer" "sodom" "megadeth")
for ((i=0; i<${#bands[@]}; i++)); do
  echo "Bands: ${bands[$i]}"
done
```

output:

```
Bands: slayer
Bands: sodom
Bands: megadeth
```

Em teoria sabemos que teremos que trabalhar com dois arrays e imprimi-los em paralelo, então fiz este (pseudo-)código:

** Mesmo sabendo que não é tão recomendável usar o `eval`, mas beleza... isso é apenas um exemplo! ;)

Utilizando o código abaixo demonstra uma 'técnica' para imprimir apenas o **id**.

```
#!/bin/bash
#uncomment to enable debug
#set -x
main() {
local idx_tab1=$(set -- {1..5} && echo ${@})
local idy_tab2=$(set -- {1..5} && echo ${@})

display=('x1=${idx_tab1[@]}' 'y1=${idy_tab2[@]}')

for id in "${display[@]}"; do
  eval ${id[@]}
done
  echo "idx_tab1: ${x1[@]//\ /$'\n'idx_tab1: }"
  echo "" # skip one line --//--
  echo "idy_tab2: ${y1[@]//\ /$'\n'tdy_tab2: }"
}

main ${@:1}
```

output:

```
idx_tab1: 1
idx_tab1: 2
idx_tab1: 3
idx_tab1: 4
idx_tab1: 5 

idy_tab2: 1
tdy_tab2: 2
tdy_tab2: 3
tdy_tab2: 4
tdy_tab2: 5
```

**Putting all together**

Exemplo 1: manual, sem loop.

source

```
#!/bin/bash
#uncomment to enable debug
#set -x
main() {
#array "name" for get "id"
local table1=("t1_nome1" "t1_nome2" "t1_nome3")
local table2=("t2_nome1" "t2_nome2" "t2_nome3")

echo "Table: 1"
echo "Column: ${table1[@]:0}"
echo $'\n'
echo "Table: 2"
echo "Column: ${table2[@]:0}"
}

main ${@:1}
```

output

```
Table: 1
Column: t1_nome1 t1_nome2 t1_nome3


Table: 2
Column: t2_nome1 t2_nome2 t2_nome3
```

Exemplo 2, com loop `while`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#uncomment to enable debug
#set -x
main() {
#array "name" for get "id"
local table1=("t1_nome1" "t1_nome2" "t1_nome3")
local table2=("t2_nome1" "t2_nome2" "t2_nome3")
local len_t=("table1" "table2")
local id=1

while [[ "$id" -lt "${#len_t[@]}"  ]];
do
  echo "Table: [$id]"
  echo "Column: ${table1[@]:0}"
  let "id = $id + 1"
  echo $'\n'
  echo "Table: [$id]"
  echo "Column: ${table2[@]:0}"
done
}

main ${@:1}
```

output:

```
Table: [1]
Column: t1_nome1 t1_nome2 t1_nome3


Table: [2]
Column: t2_nome1 t2_nome2 t2_nome3
```

De qualquer forma, para pegar o **id** das tabelas, eu tenho que acrescentar elas no array para que possa pegar o tamanho exato e fazer um loop contando desde `1` (e não do zero!) até o tamanho máximo do array. Foi o que eu fiz usando o *while*: `[[ "$id" -lt "${#array[@]}" ]]`.

Bom... eu acho que é isso que precisa! :)