# Manter Configurações ao alterar URL - Wordpress - Tema: Adventure - Organic Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou tendo problemas **nas configurações do tema** ao alterar a URL de um site wordpress usando o tema Adventure do Organic Theme.

Fiz alguns scripts para alterar as funções no banco de dados, que está ok! E funciona com outros temas perfeitamente.

Porém, o tema Adventure da empresa Organic Themes utiliza uma única coluna da tabela *wp_options* para armazenar as configurações.

**Toda vez que altero o url (com tamanho diferente) perde-se as configurações do tema.**

Notei que eles trabalham com um padrão estranho (para meu limitado conhecimento), armazenando as configurações do tema em uma única coluna, usando o tamanho do link para gerar as configurações.

Segue como setá no banco de dados, na coluna *option_value*:

```
s:12:"header_image";s:62:"http://www.yoursite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/logo.jpg";
```

Repare que o número após o *s:* representa o tamanho da string à frente: `s:62:` é o tamanho da string com a imagem *logo.jpg*.

Alterando a url para *http://newsite.com.br* tenho de ajustar não somente a url mas o tamanho indicado em `s:XX`.

Alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer essa atualização? Via plugin ou código?

Perde-se muito tempo para refazer as configurações do tema e em caso de restauração do site, este ficará desconfigurado por alguns minutos até que a configuração do tema seja toda refeita manualmente (novamente).

Grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desenvolvi um script em *bash* para solucionar o problema.

Segue abaixo o script na íntegra:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. Dados Gerais

# 1.1 URL
URL_OLD=http://very_old_url.com.br
URL_NEW=http://novo_url.com.br

# 1.2 Database
USER=db_user
PASS=db_pass
DATABASE=db_name
WP_TABLE=un_options
WP_FIELD=option_value
THEME=theme_mods_organic_adventure-child

# 2. Configurações iniciais

# 2.1 Diferença de tamanho das URL´s
VAL=$(( ${#URL_OLD} - ${#URL_NEW} ))

# 2.2 Valor atual no banco de dados
RESULT=$(mysql -u $USER -p$PASS $DATABASE -s -N -e 'SELECT '$WP_FIELD' FROM '$WP_TABLE' WHERE option_name="'$THEME'";')

# 2.3 Matrix com todos os índices que possuem ocorrência de 'http://' no banco de dados
if [[ $RESULT == *"http://"* ]]; then
    MUDAR=($(echo $RESULT | grep -b -o http | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"}{print $1}'))
fi

# 2.4 Loop para mudar o tamanho no banco de dados
for i in "${MUDAR[@]}"
do
    # 2.4.1 Busca o campo atual
    STR=${RESULT:$i-8:14}

    # 2.4.2 Busca o tamanho atual
    TAM=$( echo $STR | egrep -o "[0-9]*" )

    # 2.4.3 Roda a função se o valor for menor que 3... se for maior tem de ajustar essa parte @TODO
    if [[ ${#TAM} < 3 ]]; then
        nTAM=$(($TAM-$VAL))             # New lenght
        nSTR=${STR/$TAM/$nTAM}          # Fix the Current Number
        RESULT=${RESULT/$STR/$nSTR}     # Update the string
    fi
done

# 3. Grava no banco de dados

# 3.1 Prepara a string com barra antes das aspas duplas para gravar no mysql
RESULT=$( echo $RESULT | sed -e 's/\"/\\"/g' )

# 3.2 Atualiza o banco de dados com as novas configurações
mysql -u $USER -p$PASS $DATABASE -s -N -e 'UPDATE '$WP_TABLE' SET '$WP_FIELD'="'${RESULT}'" WHERE option_name="'$THEME'";'

return
```

Espero que seja útil a alguém também. Para utilizar o scirpt somente altere as configurações no campo '1'.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar URLs no banco de dados é preciso sempre ter em conta a mudança sem erros de valores serializados, como no seu exemplo:

```
s:12:"header_image";s:62:"http://www.yoursite.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/logo.jpg";
```

Normalmente, uso a ferramenta [**WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool**](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) quando a necessidade é simples.

Se está automatizando o processo, então vai precisar das funções PHP [`serialize()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) e [`unserialize()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... realmente, todo e qualquer plugin ou sistema de migração que pude testar não conseguiu me atender a contento. Desenvolvi um script bem "simples" em bash para solucionar a questão e resolveu o problema. Devo postar aqui meu script? Abs